# Obtain the final cookie from the request header after redirections

Tags: cookies, httpresponse, greasemonkey, puppeteer, tampermonkey

In Chrome DevTools, you can easily view the response headers of each item being loaded:

[image: Chrome DevTools]

How can I access the *final* headers programmatically like Chrome does, after any number of redirections, via Tampermonkey? If not, how about a Chrome extension? Puppeteer?

Use case:

When I access my server directly via IP from my browser, the cookie field of the request header isn't set. However, when I access it via domain name, somewhere along the way over the hosting service or whatsoever, a cookie and various fields are being added.

There can be any number of redirections along the way, and I mean literal redirections including status 302, not the normal Internet routing or proxies.

To pass the cookie to subsequent requests, I need to access the *final* cookie in the *request* header to make appropriate changes *on the client side*. There is no Set-Cookie field in the response header.

And yes, I can install scripts on the client side because the site is an 'internal' management portal for our devs. However, my server access is only partial (i.e. I cannot change the cookie-setting logic or modify it to use sessions), hence the emphasis on client side and scripts.